# What is wrong with my linear-gradient property?

Tags: css

I'm trying to solve a problem where I wrote this code:

```
body {
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #facd8a 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #facd8a 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #facd8a 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #facd8a 100%);
}
```

However, the code is still missing something. I don't know how to fix. I think I should add a CSS missing rule.

Also, why does the CSS code above seem to have the linear-gradient property repeated?

Comment: What do you think is missing and what do you want us to help fix? The repeat would be fixed by adding `background-repeat: no-repeat` as they get repeated by default.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `100%` height to the body element so that it is non-repeating. Note that since `html` is the parent of body, body needs to calculate the width from the parent. So add 100% to html as well.

Replace height with `min-height` if the body content is going to be larger than the view port height.

```css
body {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #facd8a 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #facd8a 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #facd8a 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #facd8a 100%);
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Just add height to the body should work.

Comment: Adding height to just body gives me a repeating background.

Comment: @ManojKumar: That would happen when you give `100%`. A fixed height or viewport units would work :) (I am still waiting to see what the OP thinks is missing).

Comment: @Harry But since OP is adding background to the body, I assume he wants to cover whole area. Can fixed height work in that case?

Comment: @ManojKumar: `height: 100vh` would but yeah these are minor things :)

Comment: We are still improving the solution without receiving response from OP. Yes, view port unit works fine. But what if the content is higher than the view port height. Again, small things ;) Let us wait for the OP's response and then proceed from there :D